# How do I get a list of EC2 Instances with CloudWatch Alarms?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I am writing a Python script, importing boto3, to list the EC2 instances that are being monitored by CloudWatch.  I think I have to make a list of all EC2 instances and then get another list of EC2 instances from CloudWatch and compare the two lists.  Otherwise, I am not certain how to determine whether an instance is being monitored by CloudWatch or not.  Do I use the EC2 client, CloudWatch client, or something else?

Comment: Do you have any specific example in mind? There can be many alarms based on instances.

Comment: Is it a must that you do it programmatically via a script in Python? Or do you mind a solution that uses the Amazon EC2 console?

Comment: You would use CloudWatch, because that is where the alarms are stored and managed. I think you would need to get a list of all alarms, then check what metrics each is using.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I want to do it programmatically via Python, and I want to determine which EC2 instances have CloudWatch agents installed and which ones do not.  I was going the wrong direction.  I think the information in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/troubleshooting-CloudWatch-Agent.html#CloudWatch-Agent-troubleshooting-verify-running will be helpful.